# Cannot assume role on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

My goal is for my EC2 instance in one account to read from an S3 bucket in another account. I followed the tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-instance-access-bucket/).

I have attached a role on an EC2 instance that has an inline policy that lets the EC2 assume another role in a different account.

Here's an example:

Role attached to the EC2 instance:  `RoleA` - `AccountID: 11111111111`

Role that will be assumed: `RoleB` - `AccountID: 22222222222`

.aws/config

```
[profile RoleA]
role_arn = arn:iam::22222222222:role/RoleB
credential_source = EC2InstanceMetadata
```

When I run the command `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile RoleA`,  the output should look similar to:

```
"Account": "22222222222",

 "UserId": "AROAEXAMPLEID:sessionName",

 "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::22222222222:assumed-role/RoleB/sessionName"
```

But what I see is:

```
"Account": "11111111111",

 "UserId": "AROAEXAMPLEID:sessionName",

 "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::11111111111:assumed-role/RoleA/sessionName"
```

Did I mess up in creating the roles or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use a **Bucket Policy**.

Scenario:

- EC2 instance in Account-A, using Role-A
- S3 bucket (Bucket-B) in Account-B

Add a bucket policy to Bucket-B that permits access by Role-A:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/role-a"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This permits the IAM Role used by the EC2 access to Get Objects from the bucket. No additional roles, or assuming of roles, required.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, didnt even think of this! I'll try it out tomorrow when I can get the permissions to create the bucket policy.

Comment: The EC2 IAM Role also needs to be granted permission to use `GetObject` on that bucket, but it probably already has S3 permissions. Basically, both sides need to permit it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to explicitly assume the role. For this, in your instance you have to execute [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) CLI command, e.g.:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:sts::22222222222:assumed-role/RoleB/sessionName --role-session-name <session-name> --region <region>
```

This will return a set of **temporary credentials**: `SecretAccessKey`,  and `SessionToken` and `AccessKeyId`. Having the new credentials you can export them as env variables, before using the CLI to access the S3 bucket in the other account.

The **alternative** way is to setup CLI config file with the role as shown in:

- [Using an IAM role in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)

Comment: I updated my original post with my `.aws/config` file. I couldnt follow some of what it said in that link you posted but do I mainly just need to add a trust relationship between the 2 roles?

Comment: @Sogun Hi, The tutorial you fallowed is correct and it works. I verified it myself. Must be something with the way you setup your roles, or instance profile, which are not shown in the question.